IBM MQ - Initial Setup seems to have different default credentials set
I want to use IBM MQ as a Docker Container on Windows.
The Docker Image I am trying to use is: icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq
I found this Page https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-setting-up-using-ibm-mq-console/#step-2-access-the-mq-console and wanted to access the Admin Console but was suprised that none of these listed credentials are working for me.
I am also trying to set-up the Plugin "JMS Messenger" for IntelliJ and tried any credential combination there as well but no luck.
Can it be that the freshly builded IBM MQ Container uses a different credential combination or that need to setup a admin user on my own?
EDIT:
I get the following error log in Docker Desktop:
2024-05-28 09:04:43 2024-05-28T07:04:42.832Z AMQ5534E: User ID 'admin' authentication failed [CommentInsert1(admin), CommentInsert2(jms-messenger), CommentInsert3(Pipe returned 2292 [FAILED])]
2024-05-28 09:04:43 2024-05-28T07:04:42.833Z AMQ5542I: The failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager CONNAUTH CHCKCLNT(REQDADM) configuration. [CommentInsert1(admin), CommentInsert2(DEV.AUTHINFO), CommentInsert3(CHCKCLNT(REQDADM))]


There is no default admin or app password on the container. You will need to specify them when you run the container as the environment variables MQ_APP_PASSWORD and MQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD.
eg.
 docker run --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 --volume qm1data:/mnt/mqm --publish 1414:1414 --publish 9443:9443 --detach --env MQ_APP_PASSWORD=passw0rd --env MQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=passw0rd --name QM1 icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest

There is a tutorial to get you started - Get an IBM MQ queue for development in a container

Okay, I can in fact access the console now. But for JMS Messenger and trying to connect I get this Error Message: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'. Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the queue manager to which you are connecting.  For further information, review the queue manager error logs and the Securing IBM MQ topic within IBM Knowledge Center. 

That is a new question. Please post as such.

Aren't these credential topics not related to each other? And I was already asking for this in the Question above with the JMS Messenger Plugin. But its not really related to the Plugin itself but the Connection via a JMS-Connection to the QueueManager.

The app should be using the app user and password as specified in MQ_APP_PASSWORD . If it is then the next place to look is the error logs in the queue manager container.

@Snickbrack Do you see an entry in /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM1/errors/AMQERR01.LOG ?

@richc No, just some debug loggings for some Commands I have tested, like setmqaut -m QM1 -t qmgr -p admin +all or setmqaut -m QM1 -n DEV.QUEUE.1 -t queue -p admin +all

You shouldn't need to make changes to the default developer config. The setup permits the admin user access via the admin channel to use the console and the app user via DEV.APP.SVRCONN on port 1414. This tutorial illustrates a basic JMS app connecting > https://developer.ibm.com/learningpaths/ibm-mq-badge/write-run-first-mq-app/ <
